# Can you recommend a wordpress forum plugin for a SPA?

Tags: api, wordpress, plug-in, rest, forum

I'm building a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) with frontend written in vue.js and a headless wordpress backend. Would like to add a simple forum that supports fetching posts and and/or full templates via wordpress rest api. Any recommendations? Or perhaps is it better to use an existing wordpress forum plugin with frontend included. In that case, is it bad practice to embed the forum in my spa site using an iframe?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain (in your question) what an SPA is.

Comment: And frankly yes, quering the Wordpress API and then building an interface sounds very inefficient. Wordpress is an interface system *by design*, and so are most plugins.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I added a link to wikipedia.